# Use message bundle in Java class with Seam

Tags: java, jsf, seam

I want to use my message bundle (messages_fr.properties) in a Java class with seam.

In a jsf file, all work fine like this:

```
<h2>#{msg.newCustomer}</h2>
```

But in my Java class, I tried to do this:

```
statusMessages.addToControlFromResourceBundle("refArbor", "#{messages['error_refArborDoesntExist']}");
```

or this:

```
statusMessages.addToControlFromResourceBundle("refArbor", "error_refArborDoesntExist");
```

or again this:

```
statusMessages.addToControlFromResourceBundle("refArbor", "#{msg.error_refArborDoesntExist}");
```

But the message showned is:

error_refArborDoesntExist

And not the real message.

How can I use my bundle is a Java class ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working with your solution:

```
@In
private Map<String, String> messages;
```

Just place the messages.properties in WEB-INF/classes/

Answer (score 4):

I usually inject the resource bundle, or the resource into the class and use it from there.
Example:

```
@In("#{messages['name']}")
private String name
```

Or,

```
@In
private Map<String, String> messages;
```

wich injects the resourceBundle as a Map. (make sure the it's named messages in this case).

Comment: With it, the Map messages is empty, how do you declare messages.properties in components.xml ?

Comment: Injection doesn't work in classes annotated @Entity, try the solution suggested by gadeynebram

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways you can do it.

```
StatusMessages.instance().addFromResourceBundle("msg.newCustomer);
//This will add the msg.newCustomer message to the view

String msg = org.jboss.seam.international.Messages.instance().get("msg.newCustomer);
//This will put the msg.newCustomer message in variable msg
```

Comment: What is the package for Messages class ?

Comment: org.jboss.seam.international.Messages.instance().get("some message");  will work even without a page context!   Yea!!! I can use it to set up enumerations that load their items from message bundles that are the same ones used by my JSF pages!  THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!!!!

Answer (score 1):

`String msg = org.jboss.seam.international.Messages.instance().get("key")` worked for me!

I had the same problem using an entity bean.