# Use message bundle in Java class with Seam with a parametric proprerty

Tags: internationalization, seam, seam2

The same question [Use message bundle in Java class with Seam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555712/use-message-bundle-in-java-class-with-seam) but what when you need use a parametric property like:

message.property = Some message with {0} this parameter.

How should I use the map for doing that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my solution

```
@In
private Map<String, String> messages;
String property = messages.get("property.key");
MessageFormat.format(property, params);
```

Thx https://stackoverflow.com/users/115541/mac.

Answer (score 1):

Inject the [StatusMessages](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/latest/api/org/jboss/seam/international/StatusMessages.html) component, and call one of the `addFromResourceBundle` methods. You might need to change `{0}` to `#0`; I'm not sure if the Seam components make use of the MessageFormat syntax. Also, these messages can use EL and Seam components directly: `#{myComponent.property}`, and then you don't have to pass anything else.

Comment: This was my solution

    @In
    private Map<String, String> messages;
    ...
    String property = messages.get("property.key");
    MessageFormat.format(property, params);

Thx http://stackoverflow.com/users/115541/mac.