# Resource bundle at server-side for internationale

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, ejb-3.0, seam2

I faced a problem regarding loading ResourceBundle at server-side on Seam 2.2 application.

In client side (JSF), it's OK to use the resource bundle:

```
<f:facet name="header">#{message['addTest.header.add']}</f:facet>
```

but on server-side, there's no way to use Resource bundle.

I tried following methodology but no solution works.

- add to StatusMessage: StatusMessage.addFromResourceBundle(serverity.ERROR, "key_string");
- Use injection as in this question: [Use message bundle in Java class with Seam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555712/use-message-bundle-in-java-class-with-seam)
- Load resource bundle:

  private java.util.ResourceBundle getResourceBundle() {
          org.jboss.seam.core.ResourceLoader resourceLoader = org.jboss.seam.core.ResourceLoader
                  .instance();
          java.util.ResourceBundle resourceBundle = resourceLoader.loadBundle("message");
          return resourceBundle;
      }

but result of this method is null.

Any idea or guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How exactly is `#{message}` been registered?

Comment: Defined in file components.xml:

<core:resource-loader>
  <core:bundle-names>
   <value>message</value>
  </core:bundle-names>
 </core:resource-loader>
 <international:locale-config
  default-locale="ja" supported-locales="ja en" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, the 3rd way works.

It's because I use 2 resource bundles in my project, one is messages (common) and one is myMessage.

At first, when defining resource bundle in file components.xml, I only define myMessage resource bundle.

```
<core:resource-loader bundle-names="my">
        <core:bundle-names>
            <value>myMessage</value>
        </core:bundle-names>
</core:resource-loader>
```

In file faces-config.xml, I defined language support.

```
<application>
        <view-handler>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</view-handler>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>en</default-locale>
            <supported-locale>bg</supported-locale>
            <supported-locale>de</supported-locale>
            <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
            <supported-locale>fr</supported-locale>
            <supported-locale>tr</supported-locale>
            <supported-locale>ja</supported-locale>
        </locale-config>

        <message-bundle>messages</message-bundle>

    </application>
```

And when using 3rd way, it only return messages bundle only.

To fix this, only need to add messages bundle into file components.xml and remove name in core:resource-loader.

```
<core:resource-loader>
        <core:bundle-names>
            <value>messages</value>
            <value>myMessage</value>
        </core:bundle-names>
</core:resource-loader>
```

That's it.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is the root cause, interop between Seam and EJB 3 has problem?